# Why does a QJsonArray appear to have an additional array-like depth?

Tags: json, qt

I have some JSON data that looks something like this:

```json
{
    "high_scores": [
        {
            "name": "Homer",
            "score": 1601
        },
        {
            "name": "Bart",
            "score": 1492
        }
    ],
    "an_item": "Simpson",
    "another_item": 20
}
```

which I have loaded into a `QJsonObject`. Accessing `an_item` and `another_item` both work properly. The issue is when I try to access the `high_scores` array.

I am able to get a `QJsonArray` object with this code

```
    const QJsonArray  array{obj["high_scores"]};
```

I have also tried

```
    const QJsonArray  array{obj["high_scores"].toArray()};
```

When I try to access the object elements within `array` things start going south and I start getting empty objects.

Looking in the debugger, I'm seeing an additional array-like object with `array` that appears to contain the actual data:

```
array    <1 items>
  [0]    <2 items>    <--This seems wrong to me
     [0] <2 items>
     [1] <2 items>
```

If I write something like

```
QJsonObject elem{array[0][ndx].toObject()};   // Note the extra [0]
```

then I can get to the `ndx`th element of the array, but that just doesn't seem right.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this appears to be an issue with the code generated by

```
const QJsonArray  array{obj["high_scores"].toArray()};  // new style initialization syntax
```

This code generated a call to a `QJsonValue` constructor taking a `QJsonArray` reference. This call initializes the `QJsonValue`'s `value` to a `QCborArray`, which appears to be the cause of the extra "array-like" object I was seeing in the debugger.

By going back in time a bit and using the old ways of initialization

```
const QJsonArray  array = obj["high_scores"].toArray();  // old style initialization syntax
```

generates the code I expected and solves the problem.